# do while(false) pattern

Tags: c++, macros

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Why use apparently meaningless do-while and if-else statements in macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/why-are-there-sometimes-meaningless-do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-c-c-macr)

Why is the `do while(false)` necessary in the macros below?

```
#define LOG(message, ...) \
do { \
Lock<MutualExclusion> lock (logMutex); \

 .... a lot of code ...
} while (false)
```

I dont think it serves any functional purpose. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: @Rafe: Of course, macros are pretty gross to begin with.

Comment: In `C` macros are very helpful. I am currently using macros for generic containers. In `C++` you have templates, you lucky bastards ;-)

Comment: @Rafe:  I'm not sure how this is an abuse of macros.  Macros have their place in the C/C++ language.  Macros must be structure like this so that they can easily be placed in conditional statements in code.  Its standard practice.

Comment: @Mark but why is this not a function? That's the real question.

Comment: @Mark: There's no such language as "C/C++", and there's no C tag here. Macros are sometimes necessary in C++, but they are [evil](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/misc-technical-issues.html#faq-39.5). BTW, that link is an excellent answer to this question.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/why-are-there-sometimes-meaningless-do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-c-c-macr

Comment: @Fred: Mark is right though. I agree that Macros are evil but they are great (well, better than the alternatives) for some jobs and the example in this question is potentially such a case. I do use multi-line macros for code generation sometimes (when templates won’t work) and though I atone for their use through caffeine withdrawal I’m a happier man afterwards.

Comment: Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314066/do-whilefalse

Comment: @Konrad: Yes, I sometimes use macros myself when necessary. I always go through thorough decontamination procedures afterward. ;v)

Comment: @Fred:  I'm not condoning macro use across the board.  I'm merely saying that there are cases where they are useful and probably should be used rather than other alternative (i.e. templates in C++).  They are rare for sure.  I also realize there was no C tag here, but macros are applicable (and useful) in both languages.

Comment: @Rafe:  One example is that I might create an Assert macro to halt execution and give me module and line number information.  If that is a function, the assert will trip in the function, merely reporting "Assert tripped in my_assert.cpp at line 15", rather than in the actual code location where the assert was tripped.  You can use __FILE__ and __LINE__ in a macro to get the exact location.  It might be easy for you or I to find the location at a debugger, but when random artist or designer needs to post a bug, I'd like the exact location of the assert.

Comment: If there is a lot of code it probably is an overuse of a macro, albeit that a macro for logging can be useful as it can provide __FILE__ and __LINE__ for you, and in testing libraries can also stringify what you are testing which is usually useful.

Having done those things they should ideally pass most of these to functions to do.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

It turns a block into a single statement. If you just use a block (i.e. code enclosed in `{}`) strange things can happen, for example

```
#define STUFF() \
  { do_something(); do_something_else(); }

if (cond)
    STUFF();
else
    //...
```

the extra semi-colon breaks the syntax. The `do {} while(false)` instead is a single statement.

You can find more about this and other macro tricks [here](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-12-31-c-macro-tips-and-tricks.html).

Comment: +1 for good answer.  Wish I could give another for not being an ass while so many others are.

Comment: I don't believe this affects the generated code does it?

Comment: @AlexPana In debug mode it might (compilers may leave in comparisons that always return true or false for the sake of single-stepping in the debugger having an instruction to land on for that line of code, even though that doesn't really help in this case). Or if the compiler has no optimizations at all. But otherwise, no.

Answer (score 10):

So you are forced to add semicolon at the end of the macro, when you use it. This is a common idiom and only way to enforce it.

Comment: Of course this isn't too great a reason.

Comment: @Rafe: however, it's the exact reason.

Comment: @Rafe: it’s an established standard practice. It’s commonly agreed that this is actually a *very* good reason.

Comment: @Rafe: Perhaps, but it's a pretty standard idiom in C. In C++, less so.

Comment: I seriously doubt that this is the only way to do this, but you accurately explained what it is used fro, so `+1` from me nevertheless.

Comment: The reason is not forcing users to write a semicolon at the end, but rather that the macro can be used (syntactically) as a function call and keep the syntax coherent.

Answer (score 7):

If somebody has code that does this:

```
if (something)
    LOG("My log message");
```

That would expand to:

```
if (something)
    Lock<MutualExclusion> lock (logMutex);
    // A bunch of other code
```

Which is incorrect (only the first line would be under the if statement).

The macro makes sure that the macro call is inside of a block of code.

Comment: This is half of the story, and could be achieved with just curly braces. The other half of the story is that it won't break in other constructs (the plain curly braces approach would break if used as the only statement in the `if` clause when there is an `else` clause.

Comment: Good additional information, @David.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

People use it because otherwise, you can screw up your ifs with compound statements. Imagine

```
#define hai int x; \
x = 0;

if (condition)
    hai;
else
    func();
```

Imagine what the preprocessed source looks like.

```
if (condition)
   int x;
   x = 0;
else
   func();
```

Oh wait- now our else doesn't work.

Macros like that however are typically unnecessary in C++.

Comment: Even worse, there might not even be a compile error given `if (cond) MACRO; else code;` expanding into `if (cond) if (foo) bar; else code;`.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this weird practice in #define's is to encapsulate the different assignments within a loop that is executed exactly once, so one may use the macro like a function. For example, with the code you posted, one can write:

```
if(...)
    LOG(x, y);
else
    // Something else
```

and it is expanded as

```
if(...)
    do {...} while(false);
else
    // Something else
```

This would not work without the do...while(false) surrounding the different assignments, because that would be expanded as

```
if(...)
    Lock<MutualExclusion> lock (logMutex);

// Other code... Outside the if statement!
```

Also forcing a semicolon after the macro makes it look like a function and you wont get errors because you added an semicolon like after a normal function.

Answer (score 1):

It provides local scope to that which is inside the macro.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like it is only used for scoping rules, so that `Lock<MutualExclusion>` falls out of scope at the end of the block.

If that's the reason for it, then it's completely unnecesarry:

```
// some other code...
string s = "oh hai";
{
  Lock<MutualExclusion> lock(logMutex);
  // MAGIC HAPPENS
}
s = "oh bai";
```

Comment: I think this would work in C# but not in C.

Comment: @justin: exactly the opposite.

Comment: @justin: C doesn't have destructors.  C++ is the topic at hand, rather than C#.  In any case, John, you can argue all macros are unnecessary if you are willing to manually expand their contents instead.

Comment: @Fred:  OK.  All macros are unecessary because I'm willing to expand their contents. :)

Comment: I can't argue, because I'm 99% there, too. :) However that's not the issue at hand in this question.