# How to avoid re-declare variables with C++ Macros

Tags: c++, macros

I want to write a simple Macro function. Because this macro is used in many places by different normal c++ functions, I encountered a variable scope issue. I would like to know if there is a quick way to solve it? Thank you very much.

As you can see in the attached code, depending on whether the macro is called in the function for the first time or not, I want to either declare or reuse the variable `ptrCandidate`. Note the variable scope is in the function, not in the file or translation unit. In other words, every time the macro is invoked in a new function for the 1st time, I want the top macro. And within the same function, if the macro is invoked again, I want the bottom macro.

```cpp
#define EXPECT_MY_CLASS_EQ(expectedStr, candidateStr)       \
    auto ptrCandidate = parseAndGetPtr(candidateStr);       \
    doWork(ptrCandidate);                                   \
    EXPECT_EQ(expectedStr, convertToString(ptrCandidate));

#define EXPECT_MY_CLASS_EQ(expectedStr, candidateStr)       \
    ptrCandidate = parseAndGetPtr(candidateStr);            \
    doWork(ptrCandidate);                                   \
    EXPECT_EQ(expectedStr, convertToString(ptrCandidate));
```

```
void foo(){
    EXPECT_MY_CLASS_EQ("123","abcd")
}
void bar(){
    EXPECT_MY_CLASS_EQ("111","aabb")
    EXPECT_MY_CLASS_EQ("222","ccdd")
}
```

```
void foo(){
    auto ptrCandidate = parseAndGetPtr("abcd");
    doWork(ptrCandidate);
    EXPECT_EQ("123", convertToString(ptrCandidate));
}
void bar(){
    auto ptrCandidate = parseAndGetPtr("aabb");
    doWork(ptrCandidate);
    EXPECT_EQ("111", convertToString(ptrCandidate));

    /* auto */ ptrCandidate = parseAndGetPtr("ccdd");
    doWork(ptrCandidate);
    EXPECT_EQ("222", convertToString(ptrCandidate));
}
```

Comment: You could use the [`do ... while (false);`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674480/do-whilefalse-pattern) pattern to put the macro's content inside a new scope.

Comment: Is it important to re-use the same variable? Otherwise I would just introduce a new scope in the macro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As shown in another answer, you don't need a macro in this case.

Generally speaking though, you can avoid re-definitions of variable names by the following means:

- Use of `__LINE__` preprocessor symbol (or `__COUNTER__`, though IIRC that's not standard).  Note that [creating a variable name with the preprocessor requires two levels of indirection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1489932/1116364) (replace `VARIABLE` in the link with `__LINE__`).
- A [`do { /* code */ } while(0)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674480/) ... which is AFAIK the most common way to write macros that are more than just a simple expression.
- A lambda which is immediately executed:

  `([](auto var) { /* code using var */ })(initExpressionForVar())`

Note that each of these approaches actually creates a **new** variable each time, so is semantically different from your approach with two separate macros!  This is especially important if the type of the (assigned) variable has a non-default assignment operator!

If, for some reason, you rely on the reuse of a single variable and the assignment to it, then IMO the easiest approach is to define two macros. One macro which declares the variable (and initializes it, if necessary), and another macro with the code which uses the variable.

Comment: What if, in some complicated huge program with 40 different directories nested at different levels, I use that pasty-indirection-unique-variable macro on line 10 of file blah.cpp, in directory feature1/stuff/foo/, and *just happen* to also use the same macro in baz.cpp in driver/core/bar/, and *by coincidence* it happens to be on line 10 of that file.  What exactly in this hand wavy incomplete recommendation prevents baz.cpp's "unique symbol" from colliding with blah.cpp's "unique symbol"?  (It isn't `__LINE__`, that's for sure!)

Comment: ...o/c, this comment is specifically about (and limited to) the recommendation of the use of `__LINE__` and `__COUNTER__` to generate "unique" variables (and this is easily mitigated e.g., by putting them an unnamed ns, but I would think that should have to be mentioned).

Comment: @HWalters If the probability of that happening is more than minimal to impossible then you have way too many global variables.  And all you'll get is an compiler error (redefinition).

Comment: Unnamed namespaces are IMO on a different level .. this post is about unique variable names within a translation unit. This is not about linking.

Comment: "this post is about" *This* question is about *scoped* variables, but I see nothing mentioning a single t.u.  But your *bullet* is listed under "generally speaking", which I read as importing scope (it's superfluous for *this* question *anyway*).  "probability" ...it's akin to [the birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) (two t.u.'s, same line); we're not talking won-the-lottery.  "too many globals"/"all you'll get" ...I'm reading, "if my advice bites you, you did something wrong, and my advice is still perfectly fine because if it bites you it won't hurt much".

Comment: @HWalters The questions contains code which is only valid *within* a function. Thus global variables aren't really what this question is about.  Thus I didn't include approaches for resolving the possible *linking* issues which could occur using it.  Note that the *linking* issue which you mentioned **requires** two separate translation units ... unless you merge feature1/stuff/foo/blah.cpp and driver/core/bar/baz.cpp into a single file or do some other trickery (including source files instead of headers for example).

Comment: @HWalters Long story short: What you mention *can* be a problem with this approach *when* applied to global variables *and* when not following proper practices (putting "local" definitions in an unnamed namespace). It's completely orthogonal to the questions though. Last but not least I don't "recommend" any approach here, I just list the possibilities. Which approach is suitable or not depends on the circumstances (which are - again - not the scope of the question).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192080/discussion-between-h-walters-and-daniel-jour).

Answer (score 2):

It seems regular function works:

```
void EXPECT_MY_CLASS_EQ(const char* expectedStr, const char* candidateStr)
{
    auto ptrCandidate = parseAndGetPtr(candidateStr);
    doWork(ptrCandidate);
    EXPECT_EQ(expectedStr, convertToString(ptrCandidate));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible way might be to use `__LINE__` or `__COUNTER__`  with preprocessor symbol [concatenation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html#Concatenation).

In your case, you probably don't need any macro: prefer some `static inline` function.

Here is a real-life example (using concatenation and `__LINE__`) from my [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon)'s project file [cmacros.h line 285](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/blob/master/cmacros_BM.h#L285) (it is in C, but the same trick could be done in C++)

```
#define LOCAL_FAILURE_HANDLE_ATBIS_BM(Fil,Lin,Lockset,Flabel,FcodVar,ReasonVar,PlaceVar) \
  struct failurehandler_stBM fh_##Lin                   \
   = {                                  \
     .pA = {.htyp = typayl_FailureHandler_BM},              \
     .failh_magic = FAILUREHANDLEMAGIC_BM,              \
     .failh_lockset = Lockset,                      \
     .failh_reason = NULL,                      \
     .failh_jmpbuf = {}};                       \
  curfailurehandle_BM = &fh_##Lin;                  \
  volatile int failcod_##Lin =  setjmp(fh_##Lin.failh_jmpbuf);      \
  FcodVar = failcod_##Lin;                      \
  if (failcod_##Lin) {                          \
    ReasonVar = fh_##Lin.failh_reason;                  \
    PlaceVar = fh_##Lin.failh_place;                    \
    goto Flabel;                            \
  };                                    \
  (void)0

#define LOCAL_FAILURE_HANDLE_AT_BM(Fil,Lin,Lockset,Flabel,FcodVar,ReasonVar,PlaceVar) \
  LOCAL_FAILURE_HANDLE_ATBIS_BM(Fil,Lin,Lockset,Flabel,FcodVar,ReasonVar,PlaceVar)

/// code using LOCAL_FAILURE_HANDLE_BM should probably backup and
/// restore the curfailurehandle_BM
#define LOCAL_FAILURE_HANDLE_BM(Lockset,Flabel,FcodVar,ReasonVar,PlaceVar)  \
LOCAL_FAILURE_HANDLE_AT_BM(__FILE__,__LINE__,Lockset,Flabel,FcodVar,ReasonVar,PlaceVar)
```

Back to your question, if you still want a macro: just create a block, e.g.

```
#define EXPECT_MY_CLASS_EQ(expectedStr, candidateStr)   do{    \
    auto ptrCandidate = parseAndGetPtr(candidateStr);       \
    doWork(ptrCandidate);                                   \
    EXPECT_EQ(expectedStr, convertToString(ptrCandidate));} while(0)
```