# Is it possible to escape out of a `if...elseif...else` statement like `break` does to a loop and `return` does for methods?

Tags: c#, if-statement

In my program, I have a method that has code that is used always when it is run. However, in the same method, I have `if` statements that branches off the code based on a state machine. Let's just (for simplicity) say that it's made of two values.

```
using System;
using System.Console;

int stateA = 1;
int stateB = 1;

void Main () {
     while (true) {
         Method();
     }
}

void Method () {
    Console.WriteLine("This will always be printed no matter what happens.");

    if (stateA == 1 && stateB == 1)
    {
         Console.WriteLine("State 1");
         stateB = 2;
         // goto endofifstatement;
    }
    elseif (stateA == 1 && stateB == 2)
    {
         Console.WriteLine("State 2");
         stateA = 2;
         // goto endofifstatement;
    }
    else {
         Console.WriteLine("Resetting States...")
         stateA = 1;
         stateB = 2;
         // goto endofifstatement;
    }
    // endofifstatement:

    Console.WriteLine("This will always also be printed no matter what happens.");
    Console.WriteLine("");
}
```

Now. The problem with this code right now, is that all three parts of the `if...elseif...else` block will run in every loop iteration.
Of course, there are several ways I could fix this:

- Separate (encapsulate) the `if...elseif....else` statement into its own method and use `return` to break out.
- Swap the contents and expressions for the `if` and `elseif` block, but that'd only work in this case. What happens if we have a few hundred cases?
- Use `goto`, but nobody really uses that anymore. (Commented in the snippet above)
- Use multiple `switch...case` or IF statements, nested inside each other.

## Question:

Is it possible to escape out of a `if...elseif...else` statement like `break` does to a loop and `return` does for methods?

So for the example above, the output should be:

```
This will always be printed no matter what happens.
State 1
This will always also be printed no matter what happens.

This will always be printed no matter what happens.
State 2
This will always also be printed no matter what happens

This will always be printed no matter what happens.
Resetting States...
This will always also be printed no matter what happens
```

And repeat, as opposed to:

```
This will always be printed no matter what happens.
State 1
State 2
Resetting States...
This will always also be printed no matter what happens

This will always be printed no matter what happens.
State 1
State 2
Resetting States...
This will always also be printed no matter what happens
```

Aaand repeat. Plus, if we extend this to have more than two variables and possible values, it should be able to hold up, even at the expanse of CPU speed, since we're just essentially breaking out of a block.

Comment: Maybe just throw in a `for` loop and a counter on top of `if` `else` ?

Comment: What do you mean all 3 branches run with the current code? I think you need to revisit that.

Comment: @itsme86 Yeah. I just realised.

Comment: No, there’s nothing like that. You would use `goto` for the exact equivalent, like you said.

Comment: Title question already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2314089/103167  (Yes, it also works in C#)   For your actual code, the `else` keyword is already causing exactly that behavior you mention in the comments.

Comment: To add to what itsme86 and Ben Voigt said above, the behavior assumed in the question is what you would get if you had used `if () ... if () ... if () ...`  instead.

Comment: The code you posted already does what you want. So, what's your question? You got one half-way decent answer, in that it includes a suggestion to encapsulate `if` blocks as methods and use `return` statements to exit early, but that's not actually needed in the scenario you posit here. So though the answer is okay, it's an answer to a completely different question. What question do _you_ have?

Comment: @PeterDuniho I was just fixing it up for clarity to future visitors. That answer below is half-baked and it kinda goes against what I already asked; "What happens when there are more cases and variables?" and It only answers for that particular case. Oh, and it's kinda correct. Also, the answer I was looking for is a comment :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, **goto** statement cause problems because you have to hunt for the line you want to execute next.  In addition, it can cause unexpected behaviors in particularly complex code.

You have a number of options available to you.  My preference would be to rewrite your logic so it is easier to read (**Option 1**), but I'll demonstrate the ones I see.

**Option 1: Rewrite**

```
void Method() {
    Console.WriteLine("This will always be printed no matter what happens.");
    if (stateA == 1) {
        if (stateB == 1) {
            Console.WriteLine("State 1");
            stateB = 2;
        }
        else {
            Console.WriteLine("State 2");
            stateA = 2;
        }
    }
    else {
        Console.WriteLine("Resetting States...")
        stateA = 1;
        stateB = 2;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("This will always also be printed no matter what happens.");
    Console.WriteLine("");
}
```

**Option 2: Separate method**

```
void UpdateState() {
    if (stateA == 1 && stateB == 1) {
        Console.WriteLine("State 1");
        stateB = 2;
        return;
    }
    elseif (stateA == 1 && stateB == 2) {
        Console.WriteLine("State 2");
        stateA = 2;
        return;
    }
    else {
        Console.WriteLine("Resetting States...")
        stateA = 1;
        stateB = 2;
        return;
    }
}
void Method() {
    Console.WriteLine("This will always be printed no matter what happens.");
    UpdateState();

    Console.WriteLine("This will always also be printed no matter what happens.");
    Console.WriteLine("");
}
```

**Option 3: try/finally**

```
void Method() {
    Console.WriteLine("This will always be printed no matter what happens.");
    try {
        if (stateA == 1 && stateB == 1) {
            Console.WriteLine("State 1");
            stateB = 2;
            return;
        }
        elseif (stateA == 1 && stateB == 2) {
            Console.WriteLine("State 2");
            stateA = 2;
            return;
        }
        else {
            Console.WriteLine("Resetting States...")
            stateA = 1;
            stateB = 2;
            return;
        }
    }
    finally {
        Console.WriteLine("This will always also be printed no matter what happens.");
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }
}
```

**Option 4: Encapsulation/Polymorphism**
There are a number of design patterns that would apply here.  In particular, **Strategy** and **State** come to mind.

Comment: `UpdateState()` in Option 2: Separate method does not need `return;`

Comment: @GSP: and, for that matter, the original code does not need a `break;`. The problem with the answer above is that it addresses a non-problem with code that is more complicated than the original and yet does _exactly_ the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

From what I understand, you are trying to write a cleaner code when the elseif ladder grows very long. If that the case and NOT cpu performance then you have a few options:

## State pattern

Have `interface ASuitableNameState` with method `getNextState` which return type of `ASuitableNameState`. Now you can have concrete implementations like `class StateAOneBOne : ASuitableNameState` and `class StateAZeroBOne : ASuitableNameState`.

In `StateAOneBOne` you override the method `getNextState` . There you `return new StateAOneBTwo();`

This way your if-else ladder vanishes. Your `main` can be rewritten as:

```
using System;
using System.Console;

ASuitableNameState currentState = new StateAOneBOne();

void Main () {
     while (true) {
         Method();
     }
}

void Method () {
    consolw.writeLine("A and B are");
    console.writeLine(currentState.getA + currentState.getB);
    currentState = currentState.getNextState();
}
```

The downside is, you have to create as many classes as there are `stateA` and `stateB` combinations. If the total combinations are witin (say) twenty, then this approach is feasible, otherwise not.