# What is a real life application for a 'do while loop'

Tags: c++, loops

I understand how does a do while loop works, it first runs the code once then check the condition.

What is the purpose of a 'do while loop' and is there any real life examples?

Thank you

Comment: For one thing, something you want to happen _at least once_.

Comment: what do you call "real life" ? Code in production ?

Comment: but basically, to avoid repetition of code that would be needed if you want the instruction to happen at least once. See good example from chepner's answer, for instance.

Comment: Re: "If we know the condition is false, why do we still want to run it once?" : See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314066/do-whilefalse it's a way to write a goto without writing a goto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically the only difference between while and do-while is that while loops check the loop test condition before entering the loop and do-while loops check the loop test condition after the loop is executed, both effectively having the same result except that do-while guarantees at least one execution of the loop.

Do-while loops are sometimes useful if you want the code to output some sort of menu to a screen so that the menu is guaranteed to show once.

Example:

```
int data;

do
{
   cout << "Enter 0 to quit: ";
   cin >> data;
   cout << endl << endl;
} while (data != 0);
```

You can accomplish this same thing using just a while loop also. The only difference is that you must initialize the variable to a value that would not prevent the while loop from being entered.

```
int data = 1;

while (data != 0)
{
   cout << "Enter 0 to quit: ";
   cin >> data;
   cout << endl << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You pretty much answer your own question in the first line. However, it's instructive to look at the alternatives in a language like Python, that doesn't have a `do-while` loop. The main difference is that a `while` loop checks its condition *before* executing the body, while a `do-while` loop checks the condition *after* the body. Python's general syntax doesn't allow for the second, since there's no way (that I can really think of) to attach a line of code to the *end* of an indented block.

A typical example is verifying an input value, where you want to read the first value, verify it against some condition, then continue to ask for a new value if it fails the verification. In pseudo-Python, it might look like

```
do:
    x = input("Enter yes or no")
    while x not in ("yes", "no")
```

However, Python *doesn't* have any such construct, so you either repeat the input and use a `while` loop:

```
x = input("Yes or no")
while x not in ("yes", "no"):
    x = input("Yes or no")
```

or you write an "infinite" loop with an explicit `if` statement to break out:

```
while True:
    x = input("Yes or no")
    if x in ("yes", "no"):
        break
```

Answer (score 2):

Real World Example,

Go to the bath room:

`DO {
Check_Door_Lock();
} WHILE (WAIT_WHILE_DOOR_IS_LOCKED());`

after the loop is done then the WAIT_WHILE_DOOR_IS_LOCKED() has returned a false value, so it isn't locked anymore, thus, the whole loop ends.